# Can you identify each character and spacecraft in this Star Trek TNG 30th anniversary poster?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, character-identification

Can you identify every character and spacecraft in [this poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neMa3.jpg)? Please mention the episode(s) if you can.

The poster is for the 30th anniversary of [the TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation). (First aired on September 28, 1987.)

[image]

I got many of them (along with episodes), but there are plenty I don't recognize. A few occur more than once. (e.g. - Jean Luc Picard and Tasha Yar)

Comment: https://www.dustyabell.com/collections/featured-products/products/star-trek-the-next-generation-30th-anniversary-print-set  - from the artist - there is a key available with purchase...

Comment: another question that could spring from this image: is there any episode not represented (excluding main and recurring characters of course)

Comment: @NKCampbell - Notable absences include Mr Mot, Admiral Nechayev, Captain Jellico, Quark, Molly O'Brien, Argyll, Sonya Gomez and ensigns Lt. Martinez & Kellogg.

Comment: Even Frasier Crane's in there! I love this!! I def know every face.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The original artist, Dusty Abell has provided a key on [his website](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0905/5666/products/key_watermark_2048x2048.jpg?v=1498751094)

[image]

1, **Captain Jean-Luc Picard**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
2, **Cmdr William Riker**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
3, **Lt. Cmdr Data**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
4, **Lt. Cmdr Geordi La Forge**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I  (Note incorrect, he wasn't made a Lt. Cmdr until 2x01 The Child)
5, **Ensign Wesley Crusher**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I  (Note incorrect, he was a civilian at this point)
6, **Doctor Beverly Crusher**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
7, **Counselor Deanna Troi**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
8, **Lt. Worf**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
9, **Lt. Tasha Yar**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
10, **USS Enterprise NCC-1701-D**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
11, **Holodeck Arch**, 1x01 Encounter at Farpoint, Part I
12, **Farpoint Station Entity**, 1x02 Encounter at Farpoint, Part II
13, **Seductress Tasha**, 1x03 The Naked Now
14, **Traveler**, 1x06 Where No-One Has Gone Before
15, **Badar N'D'D**, 1X07 Lonely Among Us
16, **USS Stargazer NCC-2893**, 1x09 The Battle
17, **Lwaxana Troi**, 1x11 Haven
18, **Mr Homm**, 1x11 Haven
19, **Dixon Hill**, 1x12 The Big Goodbye
20, **Bynar**, 1x15 11001001
21, **Mordock**, 1x19 Coming of Age
22, **Type 7 Shuttlecraft**, 1x19 Coming of Age
23, **Jenice Manheim**, 1x24 We'll Always Have Paris
24, **Ralph Offenhouse**, 1x26 The Neutral Zone
25, **Ian Andrew Troi**, 2x01 The Child
26, **Guinan**, 2x01 The Child
27, **Captain Thadiun Okona**, 2x04 The Outrageous Okona
28, **Riva**, 2x05 Loud as a Whisper
29, **Dr. Katherine Pulaski**, 2x07 Unnatural Selection
30, **Salia**, 2x10 The Dauphin
31, **Captain Ronald Varley**, 2x11 Contagion
32, **Type 15 Shuttlepod**, 2x13 Time Squared
33, **Kyle Riker**, 2x14 The Icarus Factor
34, **Sarjenka**, 2x15 Pen Pals
35, **K'Ehleyr**, 2x20 The Emissary
36, **Minuet**, 2x22 Shades of Gray
37, **Dr. Paul Stubbs**, 3x01 Evolution
38, **Liko**, 3x04 Who Watches the Watchers
39, **Jeremy Aster**, 3x05 The Bonding
40, **Dr. Leah Brahms**, 3x06 Booby Trap
41, **Setal/Admiral Alidar Jarok**, 3x19 The Defector
42, **Q2**, 3x13 Deja Q
43, **Lt. Richard Castillo**, 3x15 Yesterday's Enterprise
44, **USS Enterprise NCC-1701-C**, 3x15 Yesterday's Enterprise
45, **Lal**, 3x16 The Offspring
46, **Kurn**, 3x17 Sins of the Father
47, **Vash**, 3x19 Captain's Holiday
48, **Tam Elbrun**, 3x20 Tin Man
49, **Gomtou**, 3x20 Tin Man
50, **Musketeer Geordi**, 3x21 Hollow Pursuits
51, **Ambassador Sarek**, 3x23 Sarek
52, **John Doe**, 3x25 Transfigurations
53, **Lieutenant Commander Shelby**, 3x26 The Best of Both Worlds, Part I
54, **Robert Picard**, 4x02 Family
55, **Dr. Noonian Soong**, 4x03 Brothers
56, **Jeremia Rossa/Jono**, 4x04 Suddenly Human
57, **Dr. Dalen Quaice**, 4x05 Remember Me
58, **Ishkara Yar**, 4x06 Legacy
59, **Alexander Rozhenko**, 4x07 Reunion
60, **Vor'cha-class Klingon Attack Cruiser**, 4x07 Reunion
61, **Barash**, 4x08 Future Imperfect
62, **Ensign Janet Brooks**, 4x10 The Loss
63, **Keiko Ishikawa/O'Brien**, 4x11 Data's Day
64, **USS Phoenix NCC-155420**, 4x12 The Wounded
65, **Nurse Alyssa Ogawa**, 4x14 Clues
66, **Madeline**, 4x14 Clues
67, **Lanel**, 4x15 First Contact
68, **Space-faring Entity**, 4x16 Galaxy's Child
69, **Andrew Hagan**, 4x17 Night Terrors
70, **Cytherian**, 4x19 The Nth Degree
71, **Dr. Timicin**, 4x22 Half a Life
72, **Ambassador Odan**, 4x23 The Host
73, **Lieutenant Jenna D'Sora**, 4x25 In Theory
74, **Dathon**, 5x02 Darmok
75, **Type 6 Shuttlecraft**, (Episode not listed in key, but first appearance was in 5x02 Darmok)
76, **Ensign Ro Laren**, 5x03 Ensign Ro
77, **Marissa Flores**, 5x05 Disaster
78, **Ambassador Spock**, 5x07 Unification, Part I
79, **Vulcan Transport Ship T'Pau NSP-17938**, 5x07 Unification, Part I
80, **Helena Rozhenko**, 5x10 New Ground
81, **Timothy**, 5x11 Hero Worship
82, **Hanna Bates**, 5x10 The Masterpiece Society
83, **Miles O'Brien**, 5x15 Power Play
84, **Soren**, 5x17 The Outcast
85, **Captain Morgan Bateson**, 5x18 Cause and Effect
86, **Boothby**, 5x19 The First Duty
87, **Minister Campio**, 5x20 Cost of Living
88, **Kamala**, 5x21 The Perfect Mate
89, **Hugh/Third of Five**, 5x23 I, Borg
90, **Kamin/Picard**, 5x25 The Inner Light
91, **Kataan Probe**, 5x25 The Inner Light
92, **Samuel L. Clemens/Mark Twain**, 5x26 Time's Arrow, Part I
93, **Jack London**, 6x01 Time's Arrow, Part II
94, **Lt. Reginald Barclay**, 6x02 Realm of Fear
95, **Captain Montgomery Scott**, 6x04 Relics
96, **Amanda Rogers**, 6x05 True Q
97, **Ro Laren (child)**, 6x07 Rascals
98, **Sheriff Worf**, 6x08 A Fistful of Datas
99, **Dr. Farallon**, 6x09 The Quality of Life
100, **Data as Sherlock Holmes**, 6x12 Ship in a Bottle
101, **Lieutenant Aquiel Uhnari**, 6x13 Aquiel
102, **Subcommander N'Vek**, 6x14 The Face of the Enemy
103, **Deep Space 9/Terok Nor**, 6x16 Birthright, Part I
104, **Ba'el**, 6x17 Birthright, Part II
105, **Lieutenant Commander Nella Daren**, 6x19 Lessons
106, **Gowron**, 6x23 Rightful Heir
107, **Thomas Riker**, 6x24 Second Chances
108, **Professor Stephen Hawking**, 6x26 Descent, Part I
109, **Anna**, 7x02 Liaisons
110, **Captain Silva La Forge**, 7x03 Interface
111, **Dr. Sigmund Freud**, 7x06 Phantasms
112, **Doctor Serova**, 7x09 Force of Nature
113, **Maques**, 7x07 Dark Page
114, **Dr. Julian Tainer**, 7x10 Inheritance
115, **Argus Array**, 7x11 Parallels
116, **Nikolai Rozhenko**, 7x13 Homeward
117, **Ensign Sito Jaxa**, 7x15 Lower Decks
118, **Talur**, 7x16 Thine Own Self
119, **Anthwara**, 7x20 Journey's End
120, **K'mtar**, 7x21 Firstborn
121, **Jason Vigo**, 7x22 Bloodlines
122, **Emergent-lifeform**, 7x23 Emergence
123, **Future Winegrower Jean-Luc Picard**, 7x25 All Good Things..., Part I
124, **USS Pasteur NCC-58925**, 7x26 All Good Things..., Part II

Comment: Luckily I had only identified about half before I saw this answer!

Answer (score 6):

I'll start by identifying the ships:

[image: The image with each ship numbered]

1. [Deep Space Nine](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9) -- ["Birthright"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Birthright,_Part_I_(episode))
2. [USS Enterprise-D](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D))
3. A Klingon [Vor'cha class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vor%27cha_class) attack cruiser
4. [USS Pasteur](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Pasteur) -- ["All Good Things..."](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode))
5. [Kataan Probe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kataan_probe) -- ["The Inner Light"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(episode))
6. [The Argus Array](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Argus_Array) -- ["The Nth Degree"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nth_Degree_(episode))
7. [Spaceborne entity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spaceborne_entity) -- ["Encounter at Farpoint"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint_(episode))
8. A [Nebula-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nebula_class) Federation starship, probably the [USS Phoenix](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Phoenix)
9. A [Constellation-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constellation_class) Federation starship, probably the [USS Stargazer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Stargazer)
10. [Gomtuu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gomtuu) -- ["Tin Man"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tin_Man_(episode))
11. [USS Enterprise-C](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-C)) -- ["Yesterday's Enterprise"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise_(episode))
12. A member of [Junior's Species](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Junior%27s_species), probably [Junior](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Junior_(spaceborne_lifeform)) -- ["Galaxy's Child"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy%27s_Child_(episode))
13. A [Type-6 Federation shuttlecraft](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_6_shuttlecraft)
14. A [Type-15 Federation shuttlepod](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_15_shuttlepod)
15. An [Apollo-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apollo_class) starship, probably the [T'Pau](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Pau_(starship)) (thank you commentators)!
16. A [Type-7 Federation shuttlecraft](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Type_7_shuttlecraft)

Comment: 15 feels like it wants to be a Ferengi Maurader

Comment: RE: #15: Though the model was reused once or twice, that's most likely meant to be the T'Pau, from the 'Unification' two-parter. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Apollo_class

Comment: Likely the T'Pau; https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/1/1d/T%27Pau_type_studio_model.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100723214103&path-prefix=en

Comment: *shakefist* Ferengi livery though : p - the T'Pau appears on film as grey - can't argue with the shape though

Comment: The key identifies it as the T'Pau