# Who are these The Original Series characters in this image?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, character-identification

Who are the characters in this *Star Trek: The Original Series* image?

[image: TOS poster showing lots of characters on the ground crowded together, some large buildings and taller characters in the background tower of them and then the purple might sky is filled with various ships flying around]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

Comment: [Relevant meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12677/why-do-identify-all-of-these-characters-questions-get-downvoted) about mass character id questions

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - They're on topic, but that doesn't mean that people gotta like 'em

Comment: @Valorum I agree, it just seems inconsistent that the dupe target of the other Q is highly upvoted. Also The close votes seems to have been used as a mega-downvote because I don't see how they apply here, which I disagree with.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Well, I downvoted for an (apparent) total absence of research effort. Not only did OP not make any effort to identify the characters themselves, but ten seconds of googling led me to a key that shows every character

Comment: I wish there were an episode in which Q threw all of those characters together on a planet. That'd be fun to watch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you identify each character and spacecraft in this Star Trek TNG 30th anniversary poster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162632/can-you-identify-each-character-and-spacecraft-in-this-star-trek-tng-30th-annive)

Comment: @Jenayah that’s a different poster.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot my bad, copy-paste mistake

Comment: Voting to reopen it appears two of the close votes are to a duplicate that is a different question and mass id questions like this should not be closed with “Needs more focus”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [artist](https://www.dustyabell.com/) released a key on their Tumblr

[image]